# Error C2678 after migrating C++ code from VS2003 to VS2010, error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, stdvector

```
std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;

it = NULL;
do
{
    if(it == NULL)
        it = init.begin();
    else
        ++it;
    if(it == init.end())
        return 1; 
}
while(it->empty());
```

The above piece of code works fine with VS2003, but when it is migrated to VS2010, it is giving compilation error saying

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(388): could be 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> &std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>::operator =(const std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>, int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>
1>          ]
1>d:\vs2010_ws\acct ford 6.2.4 source code\acct_ford_ws\vector\src\driver\cancardxl.cpp(81): error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>
1>          ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were assuming that a vector iterator could be initialized and assigned from an int (or some form of pointer?). That's not the case.

You can transform your loop to something like:

```
if (init.empty())
  return 1;

it = init.begin();
while (it->empty())
{
  ++it;
  if (it == init.end())
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you try to assign NULL to the iterator (it's not a pointer!)
Compiler clearly says that this is not supported.
By the way, what is the reason for such assignment??

Normally if you want to run over collection you should write something like:

```
for (VectorType::iterator it = init.begin(); it != init.end(); ++it)
{
     // do something with it here   
}
```